# Importing a texture that appears to have alpha but Blender's image preview shows detail. How can I import this image with the details?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, transparency, texture-painting

I downloaded some files from PokeMiners regarding their ripped 3D models from Pokemon GO. But when I downloaded Bulbasaur, I discovered that the eye image only included the sclera, pupils, and irises.

[image]

I didn't think much of it at first, but when I brought the model into Blender and added the textures, this occurred:

[image]

No matter what I tried, I always got two results: either the alpha was see-through, or the alpha was rendered black.

Eventually, by complete accident, I stumbled upon this peculiar detail:

[image]

It turned out that the 'alpha' had some metadata that did render the material that goes around Bulbasaur's eyes (see the red circle for full texture and highlighted text for which one in particular). And using the 'Add Alpha' brush, replace the alpha with texture, resulting in:

[image]

Bulbasaur no longer looks out of place, so, technically, the problem is solved. But I do have a question that still hangs over my head: Is there a way to import an image of this caliber without the alpha being rendered as alpha and instead with the material that is missing? For example: if the original image is the first picture, how to import it with the details of the last picture below?

[image]

(Bulbasaur's Original Files Here: https://github.com/PokeMiners/pogo_assets/tree/master/3D%20Assets/Addressable%20Assets/pm0001/pm0001_00_Rig%20%2345)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Channel Packed Alpha

Change the *Alpha* setting on the *Image Texture Node* for the eyes to `Channel Packed`

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!